# Get value of selected radio button and add it to an input

Tags: jquery

I have this radio select field:

```
<div class="field">
<label for="diagnosis_sicherheit">Verdacht auf</label>
<input id="diagnosis_sicherheit_v" name="diagnosis[sicherheit]" type="radio" value="V">
<label for="diagnosis_sicherheit">Zustand nach</label>
<input id="diagnosis_sicherheit_z" name="diagnosis[sicherheit]" type="radio" value="Z">
<label for="diagnosis_sicherheit">Ausschluss</label>
<input id="diagnosis_sicherheit_a" name="diagnosis[sicherheit]" type="radio" value="A">
<label for="diagnosis_sicherheit">Gesicherte Diagnose</label>
<input id="diagnosis_sicherheit_g" name="diagnosis[sicherheit]" type="radio" value="G">
</div>
```

My question is, how can I add the selected value to the input you can see below, when an user selects one option?

```
<input id="sicherheit" name="sicherheit" type="text">
```

Comment: What jQuery/JS have you tried?

Comment: I apologize in advance for being "that guy", but why do you need to do this?  do you not have control of the backend?

Comment: I know how to add the value to the input! My problem is how to get the selectet value of the radios

Comment: @JosephMarikle its an little complicatet, but actually i work with rails!

Comment: Ah! so it's a selector question.  try looking up jQuery's [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind an event to the radio buttons. DO something like.

```
$("input[name='diagnosis[sicherheit]']").change(function() {
   $("#sicherheit").val($('input[name="diagnosis[sicherheit]"]:checked').val())
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("#sicherheit").val($('input[name=diagnosis[sicherheit]]:checked').val())
```

Comment: Works thanks! But one more thing how can i call this function when an option is selectet

Comment: yes use change event,put my code inside  $('input[name=diagnosis[sicherheit]]').change(function(){..code..})

Comment: @JohnSmith you'll need to use the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) handler

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Jsfiddle that alert the value selected

http://jsfiddle.net/rderoldan1/VyHnL/

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
alert($(this).val());
});
```

#### Update

```
$('input[name="diagnosis[sicherheit]"]').change(function(){
$('#sicherheit').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This is a simpler solution.  Won't work the same for checkboxes, but this should work for radio buttons just fine.

Comment: Yes it is. This and the other answers only differ in their selectors but this one's selector is a little vague :)

Comment: Agree with you, it was very general for all the radio buttons, I changed it to specify only by the name and show in the input